# How to set default permission of character device driver?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have created a character device driver, and i want change device driver file(/dev/cnunsr) permission to crw-rw-rw- (0666).
but the default permission is crw------- (0600), and so it doesn't change.

my character driver code is ...

```
static int cnunsr_dev_uevent(struct device *dev, struct kobj_uevent_env *env)
{
    add_uevent_var(env, "DEVMODE=%#o", 0666);
    return 0;
}

static char *cnunsr_dev_devnode(struct device *dev, umode_t *mode)
{
    printk("\n\n****%s: %d\n\n",__func__,__LINE__);
    if (mode != NULL)
        *mode = 0666;
    return kasprintf(GFP_KERNEL, "%s", dev_name(dev));;
}

int cnunsr_dev_init(void)  
{  
    int ret;  
    
    ret = alloc_chrdev_region( &id, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME );  
    if ( ret ){  
        printk( "alloc_chrdev_region error %d\n", ret );  
        return ret;  
    }  
    else printk( "cnunsr alloc_chrdev_region");
    
    cdev_init( &cdev, &simple_fops );  
    cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;  
    
    ret = cdev_add( &cdev, id, 1 );  
    if (ret){  
        printk( "cdev_add error %d\n", ret );  
        unregister_chrdev_region( id, 1 );  
        return ret;  
    }  
    else printk( "cnunsr cdev_add");
    
    class = class_create( THIS_MODULE, DEVICE_NAME );  
    if ( IS_ERR(class)){  
        ret = PTR_ERR( class );  
        printk( "class_create error %d\n", ret );  
    
        cdev_del( &cdev );  
        unregister_chrdev_region( id, 1 );  
        return ret;  
    }  
    else printk( "cnunsr class_create");
    
    class->dev_uevent = cnunsr_dev_uevent;
    class->devnode = cnunsr_dev_devnode;

    dev = device_create( class, NULL, id, NULL, DEVICE_NAME );  
    if ( IS_ERR(dev) ){  
        ret = PTR_ERR(dev);  
        printk( "device_create error %d\n", ret );  
    
        class_destroy(class);  
        cdev_del( &cdev );  
        unregister_chrdev_region( id, 1 );  
        return ret;  
    }  
    else printk( "cnunsr device_create");
    
    return 0;  
}
```

As you can see, it is 0600 even if you set dev_uevent or devnode of class.

I also tried modifying the code in system/core/rootdir/init.rc, the result is the same.

```
...
chmod 0666 /dev/cnunsr
```

My development board is juno board, and I loaded android. And I couldn't find /etc/udev/rules.d on the Juno board. therefore, Changing rules.d doesn't help to me.

I compiled my character device driver with built-in (obj-y += cnunsr.o in /linux/driver/Makefile).

somebody help me :(